# How to remove vertical white line in a sharp shape div?

Tags: html, css

I have code that shows sharp edge div.

```css
.yourButton {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.yourButton:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 40px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}

.yourButton:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 40px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="yourButton">You wanted this?</div>
```

The problem is it showed a vertical line in bigger size devices. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VpW5x/)

[image]

I have tried using `margin` or `padding` but I think its not the right thing to do since it disfigure the shape when switching to different device

Comment: like I said before (in the question you deleted to post it again and bypass the close reason), use `clip-path`.

Comment: @tacoshy I did not notice your answer since you had already closed the question. Can you post a full answer? I guess that is not the answer to the question. And I did repost my question and add the needed details; I'm not sure what you meant by bypass.

Comment: Next time, edit your question to solve the close reason in which case it can be reopened. Bypassing the close reason by deleting the answer and reposting it, will still have a negative effect on your profile that may cause a question post ban.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with 'tacking on' pseudo, or other, elements this way is that the system sometimes struggles to know what to do with positioning when it is mapping CSS pixels to screen pixels. On modern devices there can be several device pixels to one CSS pixel and one can get 'left behind' - hence the white line at some zoom levels.

To overcome this scrap the idea of using pseudo elements and make the actual element wider and clip its boundary using CSS clip path.

This snippet uses the actual px values given in the question, but you may like to think about using % values to get a more responsive result - it depends on what the end goal is of course.

```html
<div class="yourButton">You wanted this?</div>
<style>
  .yourButton {
    position: relative;
    width: 280px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    clip-path: polygon(0 50%, 40px 0, 240px 0, 100% 50%, 240px 100%, 40px 100%);
  }
</style>
```

Comment: let me try it in my end. :)